# Advice for Image Management with New Site

Tags: 7, media, files, path-aliases

I am looking for the best image management options for a new Drupal site. The original site has several thousand images, and a dynamic site is expected to explode that number to tens of thousands.

I'm currently strongly in favor of using [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) Module 2.x, particularly for the fields that come with File Entity.

My concern right now is that this solution doesn't meet some of my other needs, particularly with managing file paths. [File Field Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) and [File Aliases](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_aliases) look promising, but don't appear to work well with Media / File Entity.

What I'd like to achieve:

Fieldable files for *alt-text*, *title*, *caption*, *taxonomy*, and *pinterest caption*. Also probably source credits, and other important attributes. I will want to generate galleries from image tags (taxonomy).

I would prefer to keep the files in the default location, but serve them as if the public filesystem path is "/". IE, *`example.com/images/rest-of-path/image.jpg`*, *`example.com/pdf/document.pdf`*, etc.

I will need to brand images, and would prefer to keep the original, though not serve the penalty from using private files. Are there any modules that will enforce serving a default style? Barring that, I will learn the Drupal way of setting custom htaccess rewrite rules to achieve it.

Any advice or relevant best practices would be helpful. I seem to keep finding bits that would fit one need or another, but not necessarily work well with each other.

Comment: Use File Entity, Media, [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto).

Comment: try https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources answer for your title

Comment: @J.Reynolds: Thank you... I have Pathauto already. I don't know how Pathauto operates without File Entity, but in combination it does not appear to alter file paths. The replacement patterns given for various files only changes the path to the file's node, not the path to the file itself.

Comment: @Bala: Thank you, but I'm not sure what FileField_Sources would add to the mix. Please explain?